# Rich Snippets error: missing required field "name (fn)" when "fn" is defined

Tags: structured-data, google-rich-snippets-tool

I'm getting these errors with Google Structured Data Testing Tool:

> Error: At least one field must be set for Hcard.
>
> Error: Missing required field "name (fn)".

but the `fn` field is set. Also `vcard`:

```
<span class="vcard author">
    <a class="url fn n" href="http://www.nosabesnada.com/author/smiranda/" title="Posts by Sandra" rel="author">Sandra</a>
</span>
```

I've followed some tutorials and tried some combination, but nothing seems to work.

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What documentation, tutorial, or example are you following? Class, as far as I understand, does not expect spaces in the name value. Please help us by providing the location of the source material you are using as a guide. Thanks!

Comment: @closetnoc - As far as I know, some classes can be added to a tag separating with a space. This is one of the tutorials: http://urbanstoic.com/how-to-fix-google-hfeed-or-hcard-warnings

Comment: @closetnoc - The error persists if I use just `fn` in the class.

Comment: Okay. Thank You! I can learn something new and I and others will know where you are coming from. I have some business I have to attend to now, but I will look when I can. Hopefully, you will have an answer sooner than that.

Comment: Are you using Wordpress?

Comment: Have you tried class="fn url n" where fn is the first option in the list?

Comment: I looked at http://www.seoskeptic.com/structured-data-for-author-pages-and-linked-snippets/. I also noticed that you are using class="vcard author". In the example on this linked page (about 2/3rds the way down), they are using class="vcard". I am not sure if these things make a difference. I really do not use micro data. I have dabbled in schema.org mark-up of course. Let us know. BTW- This site is often cited and I have found references on the site that have really helped in the past. Hopefully, there are some clues there for you.

Comment: @closetnoc - I've tried with your suggestions, but nothing changes. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<span class="vcard author">
<a rel="author" title="author profile" href="http://example.com/author/name/">
<span class="fn author">Author Name</span>
</a>
</span>
```

You need to add **class="fn author"** in the second span tag.

After you update the code go and [test it out.](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets)

Your errors should go away gradually within a week or so.

Comment: Yes! The errors have disappeared. But also I've added a class "url author" to the link tag, and it is also displayed on Structured Data Testing Tool. Thanks ;)

Comment: Great! Glad it all worked out.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Disable this]

I fixed it by disabling this exactly, only this worked finally!. I even disabled all plugins and still got the error, so found it... :)